# Is keeping this spatial index only in Memcache a sound approach?

Tags: google-app-engine, indexing, geospatial, geofencing

The spatial index used in [this](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/building-scalable-geofencing-api-on.html) Geofencing tutorial for App Engine is stored only in Memcache so it can be wiped out anytime and would need rebuilding from scratch every time this happens.

Wouldn't this approach prove costly and time consuming if there are too many geofences to index? Is there any better solution that can keep the index persistent?

Comment: You send it to memcache for quick reference, and at the same time, you send it to the datastore for permanency (you can even send to the datastore async to make your app more responsive). Or use the python "ndb" which does it naturally (hits memcache first, datastore second)

Comment: How would you serialize the index object from Java Toplogy Suite (JTS) that has been used here so that it can be persisted in the datastore?

Comment: I don't know JTS, but if it can be sent in the memcache, it has to be serializable, no? why not simply send the same exact object to datastore? or send it as a blob, where it doesn't matter how it's serialized

Comment: They have passed the entire index as the value to be stored in a Memcache put call. Memcache seems to be able to automatically serialize any Java object, but saving in the Datastore would require me to handle the serialization. Saving to the Blobstore seems like a better idea, thanks!